# Autofilled calculating form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I have a `<select>` with products, when  an option is selected the `input` `#price` is autofilled with the `data-price`, then enter the quantity in the input `#quantity` and finally in the input `#sum` is a result from `price*quantity`. How to make it sum on changing the inputs and select?

```js
$('#product').change(function() {
  var price = parseInt($(this).children("option:selected").attr("data-price"));
  $("#price").attr("value", price);
});

$('#quantity').on('input propertychange paste change', function(e) {
  var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="product">
      <option value="1" data-price="100">Product 1</option>
      <option value="2" data-price="200">Product 2</option>
      <option value="3" data-price="300">Product 3</option>
    </select>
<input type="text" id="price" value="" readonly>
<input type="number" id="quantity" min="1" max="9999999" step="1">
<input type="text" id="sum" readonly="">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an additional "calculate total" function, and call it from both event handlers. The total will update whenever either is changed.

```js
$('#product').change(function() {
  var price = parseInt($(this).children("option:selected").data("price"));
  $("#price").val(price);
  calcTotal();
});

$('#quantity').on('input propertychange paste change', function(e) {
  calcTotal();
});

function calcTotal() {
  var price = $('#price').val() || 0;
  var qty = $('#quantity').val() || 0;
  var total = price * qty;

  $('#sum').val(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="product">
  <option value="1" data-price="100">Product 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-price="200">Product 2</option>
  <option value="3" data-price="300">Product 3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="price" value="" readonly>
<input type="number" id="quantity" min="1" max="9999999" step="1">
<input type="text" id="sum" readonly="">
```

Answer (score 1):

To capture the value of `quantity`, you can use `blur` method. When ever user removes focus from the input box, the `blur` function will be called and sum will be calculate.

Also, you can create a module `displaySum` method to get the value of `price` and `quantity` input and update the `sum` input.

```js
$('#product').change(function(){
    var price = parseInt($(this).children("option:selected").attr("data-price"));
    $("#price").attr("value",price);
    displaySum();
});

$('#quantity').on('blur', function(e) {
    displaySum();
});

function displaySum() {
  let price = parseInt($('#price').val());
  let quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
  if(isNaN(price)) { price = 0; }
  if(isNaN(quantity)) { quantity = 0; }
  let sum = price * quantity;
  $('#sum').val(sum)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="product">
  <option value="1" data-price="100">Product 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-price="200">Product 2</option>
  <option value="3" data-price="300">Product 3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="price" value="" readonly>
<input type="number" id="quantity" min="1" max="9999999" step="1">
<input type="text" id="sum" readonly="">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#quantity").val() > 0)
{
    $("#sum").val(parseInt(quantity, 10) * parseInt($("#price").val(),10) );
}
```

add the following line. It will multiply the quantity with the price and set it to the sum input.

```js
$('#product').change(function(){
    var price = parseInt($(this).children("option:selected").attr("data-price"));
    $("#price").attr("value",price);
    $("#quantity").trigger("input"); //this line will update any reflections to the change in product.
});

$('#quantity').on('input propertychange paste change', function(e) {
    var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
    if ($("#quantity").val() > 0)
    {
        $("#sum").val(parseInt(quantity, 10) * parseInt($("#price").val(),10) );
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="product">
  <option value="1" data-price="100">Product 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-price="200">Product 2</option>
  <option value="3" data-price="300">Product 3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="price" value="" readonly>
<input type="number" id="quantity" min="1" max="9999999" step="1">
<input type="text" id="sum" readonly="">
```